# Ruby string substitution with multiple options

Tags: ruby, string-substitution

I want to do string substitution. With `gsub` or `tr` I can give a single input character and map it to a single output value but I want to create multiple output strings based on multiple mappings:

```
swap = { 
  'a' => ['$', '%', '^'],
  'b' => ['3'],
  'c' => ['4', '@'],
}
```

For input string `'abc'`, I should get the following output strings:

- `'$34'`
- `'$3@'`
- `'%34'`
- `'%3@'`
- `'^34'`
- `'^3@'`

Is there an easy way to do this for an arbitrary number of inputs and mappings? In reality it is likely to be about 10 inputs and at most 3 mappings, usually only one.

Comment: It's as simple (in this case) as having three nested loops (which enumerate all combinations) and in the innermost loop you call tr/gsub.

Comment: Although making a generic implemenation is, at least, non-trivial, I admit. Give it a try, though.

Comment: Robin, thanks for choosing my answer, but you really should wait awhile (perhaps 2+ hours) before awarding the greenie. A quick selection can discourage other answers and, imo, is discourteous to others still working on answers. There's no rush. Please consider removing the checkmark and deciding later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def gen_products(swap, str)
  swap_all = Hash.new { |_,k| [k] }.merge(swap) 
  arr = swap_all.values_at(*str.chars)
  arr.shift.product(*arr).map(&:join)
end
```

See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) (with a block), [Hash#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product). If `h = Hash.new { |_,k| [k] }` and `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns `[k]`.

```
swap = { 'a'=>['$', '%', '^'], 'b'=>['3'], 'c'=>['4', '@'] }

gen_products(swap, "abc")
  #=> ["$34", "$3@", "%34", "%3@", "^34", "^3@"]
```

Here

```
swap_all = Hash.new { |_,k| [k] }.merge(swap) 
  #=> {"a"=>["$", "%", "^"], "b"=>["3"], "c"=>["4", "@"]}
vals = swap_all.values_at(*str.chars)
  #=> [["$", "%", "^"], ["3"], ["4", "@"]]
```

Another example:

```
gen_products(swap, "bca")
  #=> ["34$", "34%", "34^", "3@$", "3@%", "3@^"]
```

and one more:

```
gen_products(swap, "axbycx")
  #=> ["$x3y4x", "$x3y@x", "%x3y4x", "%x3y@x", "^x3y4x", "^x3y@x"]
```

Here

```
swap_all = Hash.new { |_,k| [k] }.merge(swap)
  #=> {"a"=>["$", "%", "^"], "b"=>["3"], "c"=>["4", "@"]}
vals = swap_all.values_at(*str.chars)
  #=> [["$", "%", "^"], ["x"], ["3"], ["y"], ["4", "@"], ["x"]]
```

Comment: Oh, that's clever :) Forgot about `.product`. Reimplemented it recursively. Which doesn't look as sexy.

Comment: You can decompose the array(s) during assignment via `first, *others = swap.values_at(*str.chars)` in order to shorten the method's second line to `first.product(*others)`

Comment: Good idea, @Stefan. I knew there was something not quite right. I'll change it. Thanks.

Comment: @Stefan,you *missed something*!! I could hardly believe my eyes. Thinking that `product` (like `combination`, `permutation`, etc.) returned an enumerator, I had tacked on `.to_a`. But it then dawned on me that it returns an array, so I just removed `.to_a`.

Comment: @Stefan, another (less desirable, imo) way is `arr = swap.values_at(*str.chars); arr.shift.product(*arr)`.

Comment: I've had second thought on `arr.shift.product(*arr)` being inferior. It does only require that a single variable be defined.

Comment: Just realised, this fails if there are characters in str that aren't in the swap array, i.e. you call it like this: `gen_products(swap, "abcxyz")` is that an easy fix?

Comment: What I'd like is to leave the xyz on the end of all the swaps.

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, didn't get any email alerts from SO. That fixed it, thanks very much.